# Purpose of authentication on API's?

Tags: rest, api, authentication, http-request

After asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990484/integrating-an-api-with-mobile-app-or-website-and-ajax) I found that I have a different question. What's the purpose of authenticating an API anyway?

Take Twitter for instance. If you want to use this link to load some user's posts:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name={username}
```

Then you have to authenticate.

**HOWEVER**, why would you when you can just make an HTTP request to:

```
https://twitter.com/i/profiles/show/{username}/timeline
```

Which does the same exact thing, except requires no authentication?

So why would I need authentication? Also, I don't see how authentication can ever make the use of an API exclusive to a particular app/etc.; can't you always make the same HTTP requests from another app? The referrer can be spoofed as well, so I really don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

Authentication on APIs allows the server to verify that the client making the request has the authorization (i.e. privileges) to take whatever action the request encapsulates.

Sticking to your Twitter example, direct messages are private to a user, so in order to allow access to them, Twitter must verify that the client has valid credentials for that user account.